# Is there any canon information about how gravity is controlled?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends

Ships of Star Wars all have artificial gravity even when within other gravitational fields. Some ships weaponize gravity to pull others out of hyperspace. Technology has clearly progressed to a point where organisms understand and can alter gravity at will.

Is there ever any canon discussion of how they are able to do this? If there isn't current canon I'm also interested in Legends information on the development or implementation of gravity-altering technology. I'm thinking *Ender in Exile* esque, where Card explains how fractional lightspeed travel and instantaneous communication occurs to a relative degree of specificity--obviously not with real science, but with believable theories.